# How can I find the dynamic height of an Angular 7 div?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, viewchild

I am just trying to console.log how tall a div is based on the size of it expanding based on the table inside of it. I need this to determine if a scroll bar will be present (this is contained in a dialog pop-up).

Currently I have it working to display the height set in the div, but it does not update based on the table. Any ideas where I am messing this up?

**HTML**

```html
<mat-dialog-content style="height: 460px">

  <div #target style="height:100px">
<table  class="responstableModt">
  <tr *ngFor="let result of results; let x = index">
    <td width="9%" style="text-align: right">{{ result.AMT_OWED | number : '1.2-2' }}  </td>
    <td width="9%" style="text-align: right">{{ result.AMT_PAID | number : '1.2-2' }}  </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

 
      
    </mat-dialog-content>
```

**Component**

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit , ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DbService } from '../db.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IssuerService } from '../../issuer.service';
import { HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cf-iteration-dialog',
  templateUrl: './cf-iteration-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../global.css']
})

export class CfIterationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private DbService: DbService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CfIterationDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }


  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }


    runGetData(repid, issuerid, iterid) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.DbService.GetData(repid, id, iterid).subscribe(results => this.results = results,
        (err) => { 
          console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err)); 
      },
      () => {
        this.IterDiabled = false;
        // Get the height of the element
        const height = this.targetElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight;

        // Here you can use the height!
        this.result = height;
        console.log('x: ' + height);
        resolve(1);});})
      }
  

  async ngOnInit() {
    // Get Details Data
    try { await this.runGetData(this.repid, this.id, this.iterid)
    } catch (e) {console.log('Try/Catch Error: ' + e)}

   }

   @ViewChild('target') targetElement: any;    
   result: string;

}
```

Currently it consoles 100 no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the layout properties of angular material? :

https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

In you're case, you just have to use the "stretch" property if you want a 100% height.

If you're using Angular, you should definitely use Angular material, it's very easy to implements and you can set the number of rows with a pagninator (a little bit more nice than a scroll bar for me):

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I am trying to get the height of the material table based on how many rows it has. So if the table has 50 rows it height will be say 1000px causing a scroll bar to appear. If it has 2 rows it may only be 100px so there will be no scroll bar.

Is there anyway to determine this? This data set needs to be scrollable as it displays best that way.

Comment: no, because the number of rows depends of the screen definition. That's why you should implements a mat-table and set the number of entries. If you have a design problem, you should post a picture (best way to explain).